# How to install and run an apk file in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, installation, apk, sd-card

I want to install and run apk file in my SD card. I have code through which I'm trying to fetch the apk file but I have no clue how to install and open it.  This is my code so far

**MainPage.Xaml.cs**

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             DependencyService.Get<SDCard>().ApkInstall();

        }
```

**SDCardInstall.cs** in native android

```
 public class SDCardInstall: SDCard
    {
        public void ApkInstall(string filename)
        {
   var filename = "XYZ.apk";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The file name is"+filename);
            var path = "Install apk/";
            var destination = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath.ToString(),path+filename);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The destination is"+destination);
            //Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.("file://" + destination);
            Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTask);

            //install.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            install.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath.ToString()+ "/Install apk/"+ filename)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
             Forms.Context.StartActivity(install);
     }
    }
```

I have mentioned the following **permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTANT_APP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

App is not installing.I get the installation page of the APK where I have to install the APK manually.But I need the APK to get installed automatically through code.